# Find previous matching element in a cyclic list

Tags: python

I have a list of `True` and `False`, which is considered cyclic (first element comes after the last one). What is the better way to find index of the closest `True` element, *preceding* an element with the given index?

Here is my solution. It is very straightforward, but not very pythonic, as I think:

```
def prev_element(a, i):
    i -= 1
    while not a[i]:
        i -= 1
    return i % len(a)
```

This will raise `IndexError` in case there is no such element, which is ok for me. I exploit the fact that a list may be indexed with negative indices, which makes the list cycling. Any better solutions? Some cool one-liner, maybe?

Comment: I think your solution is perfectly fine! No need to be clever for dogmatic reasons, any more than your solution "should" use the Visitor pattern or Abstract Base Classes.

Comment: It works, it is short and sweet and uncomplicated and readable -  what is un-pythonic about it ?

Comment: @Cuadue I'm new to python, that's why I thought there may be some fancy feature or approach I do not even know about. Now when I see the answers, I'm sure that my solution is at least not worse than others.

Answer (score 3):

```
from itertools import  count

def prev_element(a, i):
    cyc = count(i - 1, -1)
    res = next((next(cyc) + 1 for _ in range(len(a)) if a[next(cyc)]), None)
    return res % len(a) if res else res
```

You can use max with a try/except using a lambda to get the max, under the constraint that it cannot be less than the index we are searching from, if we have no index below it will get the index above.

```
def prev_element(a, ind):
    try:
        return max((i for i, ele in enumerate(a) if ele and i != ind), key=lambda x: (x < ind, x))
    except ValueError:
        return None
```

Without a try/except use a list:

```
def prev_element(a, ind):
    inds  = [i for i, ele in enumerate(a) if ele and i != ind]
    return max(inds,key=lambda x: (x < ind, x)) if inds else None
```

Comment: Your answer doesn't cycle

Comment: @Mikhail, it does now and won't throw an indexError

Comment: Ok, thank you for showing the different approaches. Now I can leave my original approach, but do it knowledgeably.

Answer (score 1):

I would do this

```
def prev_element(seq, idx):
    for new_idx,el in enumerate(reversed(seq[:idx])):
        if el == True:
            return idx - new_idx
```

The other option is:

```
def prev_element(seq, idx):
    max(i for i,el in enumerate(seq[:idx]) if el==True)
```

Or even:

```
def prev_element(seq, idx):
    min([i for i,el in enumerate(seq) if el==True], key=lambda i: abs(idx-i))
```

Comment: The other option doesn't cycle and in the third the key isn't a function

Comment: @JuniorCompressor I'm unsure if his data structure is handling the looping or if we're coding that in.

Answer (score 1):

An improvement over [JuniorCompressor's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28441517/648265), the most simple&stupid(r) approach:

```
next(i%len(a) for i in range(n-1,n-len(a)-1,-1) if a[i])
```

where `n` is the index of the initial value.